# No log file created when calling UseWindowsService

Tags: c#, serilog, asp.net-core-5.0

I followed the [Serilog instructions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) to add a very basic log file to my application.

I am able to reproduce it doing the following:

- Created a new `ASP.NET Core Web Api` with Visual Studio with the default parameters: .NET 5, no authentication, configured for HTTPS, enabling OpenAPI support
- Installed the `Serilog.AspNetCore` package
- Installed the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` package (so I could call the `UseWindowsService()` extension method)
- Edited my `Program.cs` class as follow:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .WriteTo.File("logs.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting Web Host");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .UseSerilog()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

- Removed the Logging section from the app.settings:

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

So far, when I run the web api from Visual Studio or the windows explorer, everything works great: the file `logs.txt` is created as expected and the web api is alive.

But then, when I create a windows service to run the app:

```
sc.exe create TestService binPath="path\to\WebApplication1.exe"
```

Despite the web api running well, there is no log file created.

Here is some of the things I tried:

- Changed the user running the service with my own account => no change
- Removed the call to `UseWindowsService()` => the web api does not start
- Used another provider (NLog) => same behavior: no log file created
- Switched the calls between `UseWindowsService()` and `UseSerilog()` => no change
- Called `UseWindowsService()` and `UseSerilog()` (in both order) after `ConfigureWebHostDefaults()` => no change

What did I do wrong? May be the whole `run as a windows service` part is not the best way to run my web api as a service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first rule of Serilog troubleshooting is to enable [`SelfLog`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics) and see what error messages are being thrown by the Serilog sink.

---

Most likely it's a permission issue (i.e. the account doesn't have permission to write to the folder you're attempting to write to).

`.WriteTo.File("logs.txt", ...)` writes to the current working directory, and in the case of Windows Services usually means `%WINDIR%\System32` - which I'm sure it's not the place you want to store your logs anyway.

Thus you need to be more explicit about the path you want to write your logs to, and make sure it points to a folder the account used for running the service will have write access to.

A common pattern is to define the path in a configuration file (e.g. `appSettings.json`) and retrieve that.

If you're looking to write to the same folder where your Windows Service binaries are, a reliable way nowadays is to use `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule?.FileName` (*1*). E.g:

```
var startupPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule?.FileName);
var logFilePath = Path.Combine(startupPath, "logs.txt");

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .WriteTo.File(logFilePath, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();
```

---

(*1*) In a future version of .NET, you'll be able to use [`Environment.ProcessPath`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40862#issuecomment-680189514) or [`Environment.ApplicationDirectory`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/41341)

Comment: I thought `UseWindowsService()` changed the root dir (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) but it looks like it's not ...