# Serilog not recording logs to file when i publish app

Tags: serilog

I'm using this guide to quickly setup logging to a file in an asp.net core app with the least hassle.

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file

I seem to be getting logs but they are more like default logs of program startup and api requests. The logs that i'm writing with the below code are not appearing in the text file

```
            _logger.LogInformation("important logs here");
```

Second problem is that when i publish my application, it runs fine but does not produce any log files.

Below is my program class

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                }).ConfigureWebHost(config =>
                {
                    config.UseUrls("http://*:5050");

                }).ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, builder) =>
                {
                    builder.AddFile("Logs/myapp-{Date}.txt");
                })
                .UseWindowsService();
    }
```

Comment: Enable [`SelfLog`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics) and see what error messages are being thrown by the Serilog sink.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No log file created when calling UseWindowsService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68745656/no-log-file-created-when-calling-usewindowsservice)