# Serilog logging to file in worker service .net core 3.1

Tags: logging, .net-core, serilog, worker-service, serilog.extensions.logging.file

I am new to worker service.I have created worker service in .net core 3.1.
Referred this tutorial [File logging in .Net 5 worker service using serilog.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HLPo2U_qlM)
It is working as expected, i.e it is logging to the file.
Now i installed the service i had have to use

> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices

and modify the code as below.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddSerilog();
        })
       .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        }).UseWindowsService(); // This is the change i required to install as service
```

Now when i am running the service, it is not logging to the file.
Am i missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No log file created when calling UseWindowsService](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68746437/211672)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WindowsService` are run in `System32` folder. for example:
`C:\Windows\System32`

You should check this folder for your logs.

Or you should add full path address to logs path.

Comment: This is genius! Has had me stumped for a while now. Is there a way to have it in the path that the service is in? So in debug, command prompt this works as expected?